# How to zip multiple observables (1kk) without preallocation them in array

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have a function, that represent single asynchronous insertion in db:

```
function insertInDatabaseRx(data) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
           db.insert(data, function (err) {
               if (err) {
                  observer.onError(err);
               } else {
                  observer.onCompleted();
               }
           });
    });
}
```

I need to do mass insertion(1kk+ times) and do some action after all done. My current implementation:

```
var someLongArray = ...;

var massInsertion = [];
for (var i = 0; i < someLongArray.length; i++) {
    massInsertion.push(insertInDatabaseRx(someLongArray[i].data);
}

Rx.Observable.zip(massInsertion)
    .subscribe(
        function (x) {
            logger.debug('Next: %s', x);
        },
        function (e) {
            logger.error('Error: %s', e);
        },
        function () {
            //all done
            logger.info('all save done, terminating ... ');
            process.exit();
        });
```

It's worked, but I think it's not resource(cpu/mem) efficient to preallocate array of observables:

```
var massInsertion = [];
for (var i = 0; i < someLongArray.length; i++) {
    massInsertion.push(insertInDatabaseRx(someLongArray[i].data);
}
```

How do carry out this task more efficient, without preallocation array of observables?

Comment: first thing I notice is that `insertInDatabaseRx` does not obey observable contract. You should not emit `onCompleted` after calling `onError`. An `else` is all you need to fix that bit.

Comment: @DaveMoten thanks!

Comment: Where is `data` coming from? Is it coming from an array? Are you sure your db does not have a bulk insertion operation?

Comment: @paulpdaniels Yes it's coming from array and db does not have bulk a insertion. For me would be good blocking insertion, because it runs on application exit, but db doesn't has sync api, also in rxjs I not see `.toBlocking` method like rxjava has.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a forkJoin()

```
function insertAll() {
    var rxResult = insertInDatabaseRx(someLongArray[0].data);

    for (var i = 1; i < someLongArray.length; i++) {
        rxResult = rxResult.forkJoin(
            insertInDatabaseRx(someLongArray[i].data),
            function (result1, result2) {
                return result1 + result2;
            });
    }

    rxResult.map(...);
}
```